# React component with infinite update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a React component and there will be an infinite update on the component whenever I connect it to redux and reference to properties from the store. If I just reference/connect one property from the store, the infinite update will not occur. It only happens when I connect two or more and I really cannot determine why this is happening.

When I add shouldComponentUpdate, it will actually not stop the infinite updating, it will just slow it down a lot. I really have no idea what is going on.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class UnreadMessages extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            messageReceived: false,
            unreadMessages: 0
        }

        this.unreadMessages = 0;
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (prevProps.lastViewedMessageTime === this.props.lastViewedMessageTime) {
            this.setState({ messageReceived: true }, 
                () => {
                    setTimeout(
                        () => {
                            this.setState({ messageReceived: false });
                        }, 
                        300
                    );
                }
            );
        }

        const conOne = prevProps.messages.length !== this.props.messages.length;
        const conTwo = this.props.visible === false && window.innerWidth < 768;
        if (conTwo) {
            let index = this.props.messages.length - 1;
            const conOne = this.props.messages[index].type === 'chat.msg';
            const conTwo = this.props.messages[index].member_type === 'agent';
            if (conOne && conTwo) {
                this.setState({ 
                    unreadMessages: this.state.unreadMessages + 1 
                });
            }
        }

        if (this.props.visible === true) {
            this.setState({ unreadMessages: 0 });
        }
    }

    render () {
        let displayBadge = this.state.unreadMessages > 0 ? true : false;
        console.log('DISPLAY BAD', displayBadge)
        let pulse = this.state.messageReceived === true ? 'pulse' : '';
        console.log('PULSE', pulse)

        if (!displayBadge) {
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <span className={`msgBadge ${pulse}`}>{this.state.unreadMessages}</span>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    lastViewedMessageTime: state.lastViewedMessageTime,
    messages: state.chats.toArray(),
    visible: state.visible
  };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(UnreadMessages);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the callback to setState in your componentDidUpdate?  It doesn't seem useful to setState, then unset it 300 ms later.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you mean by 'infinite update'?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the state in `componentDidUpdate` which causes the infinite render as `lastViewedMessageTime` remains the same.

Hence, it checks the condition `if (prevProps.lastViewedMessageTime === this.props.lastViewedMessageTime)` which will be true since you are not changing it, so it will again update the state, so on and so forth.